# How to create a TextView with default shape as square and auto-adjustable height when content cannot fit into?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to create a custom TextView which is square by default but if the text cannot fit into, the height increases automatically to accommodate the content.

I tried setting the height to `wrap_content` and overriding the `onMeasure()` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int newHeight = heightMeasureSpec > widthMeasureSpec ? heightMeasureSpec : widthMeasureSpec;
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, newHeight);
}
```

But that did not work.

**When content is less, it's fine.**
[image: SquareView when content is small]

**But when content is more, the height should expand but it doesn't. A lot of text is clipping out** 
[image]

Comment: A screenshoot would be great as well so we can see better the issue

Comment: Hey @Skizo-ozᴉʞS, I've added screenshots

Comment: So what you want is the first imagge make the "card" smaller?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS, No, the opposite. In the second image there's a lot more text after "YOU". I want the height to increase if there's more text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `setMinHeight` to achieve this purpose

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int minHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    setMinHeight(minHeight);
}
```

And set `wrap_content` to `layout_height` in layout:

```
<com.test.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/squareTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

Update for RecyclerView:

1.Get screen width inside Activity class:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;
```

2.Pass it to adapter and set when create item view:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View root = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_item, viewGroup, false);
    root.setMinimumHeight(screenWidth);
    return new ViewHolder(root);
}
```

Comment: This only works when the second time list item is in view.
Initially the textview seems to be in wrap_content mode, then when I scroll and the view goes out of scope, it resizes to squareview